# Código me devuelve datos incorrectos

Tags: c++

El programa debería darme la suma de la cantidad de letras en x números de palabras, en las palabras:

```
Palabra  
Hola  
Como  
Esta    
//suma resulta ser igual a: 14291811
```

Suma debería ser igual a la suma del arreglo `longitud[v]`, pero me devuelve valores que no corresponden

**Mi código**

```
int v=0;
void MuestraDatos(ifstream& arch_Datos){
    string texto;
    while(!arch_Datos.eof()){
        getline(arch_Datos,texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;
        v++;
    }
    arch_Datos.close();
    
}

void EDT(ifstream& arch_Datos){//EDT=Ejercicios con los DaTos
    string texto;
    int i=0;
    int suma;
    float media;
    int longitud[v];
while(!arch_Datos.eof()){
    getline(arch_Datos,texto);
    longitud[i]=texto.length();
    cout<<longitud[i]<<endl;
    i++;
}
int c=0;
while(c<v){
suma=suma+longitud[c];//lugar donde le entro los datos a suma
c++;
}
**cout<<suma<<endl;**//lugar del problema
arch_Datos.close();
}
```

Comment: Qué vale `v` dentro de la función `EDT()`? Es una variable global?

Comment: Vendría a valer 4, por la cantidad de palabras, esta declarada global y vale la cantidad de saltos de líneas que tiene el .txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu metodo EDT tienes  un pequeño gran  problema y que te lo explico mediante  lineas  de comentario:

```
void EDT(ifstream& arch_Datos){//EDT=Ejercicios con los DaTos
 
    string texto;
    int i=0;        //  Correcto i tiene un valor  inicial = 0
    int suma;       //  Variable no inicializada cualquier valor.
    float media;    //  Igual al anterior 
//    int longitud[v]; //  Arreglo sin  inicializa
    int *  longitud = new int[v]; //  Nueva versión (ver  comentario  de @eferion

     while(!arch_Datos.eof()){
         getline(arch_Datos,texto);
         longitud[i]=texto.length();  // Asigna un valor correcto.
         cout<<longitud[i]<<endl;
         i++;
     }
     int c=0; // Correcto.
     while(c<v){
        // suma = suma + que valor  puede  tener esta variable no inicializada. Puede como  no puede estar  en  0. Por lo tanto, tu suma siempre  debería salir como resultados diferentes
        suma=suma+longitud[c];//lugar donde le entro los datos a suma
        c++;
       }
       **cout<<suma<<endl;**//lugar del problema. El problema  viene de mas  arriba, aqui solo lo presenta
       arch_Datos.close();
     }
```

Tienes que inicializar tus  variables:

```
    int suma = 0;       
    float media = 0.0f;
```

Comment: Gracias, tu comentario me fue me mucha ayuda.

Comment: Ok, Si te sirvió marca la respuesta .

Comment: Se te olvidó comentar que dado que `v` es una variable, `longitud[v]` es una VLA o Variable Length Array, una característica **no permitida** en el estándar de C++ y, por tanto, algo a evitar. `longitud` debería ser un simple puntero e inicializarse con `new[]`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es incorrecto ya en las primeras líneas de `EDT`. Utilizas Formaciones de Longitud Variable ([VLA en inglés [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), los cuáles no pertenecen al C++ estándar si no que son una extensión del compilador (Lee sobre la extensión en [el compilador GCC [image]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)). Cada compilador tiene sus propias extensiones de manera que es posible que este código te funcione en determinados compiladores.

Según el [estándar de C++ [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 8.3.4 Formaciones
>
> 1. En una declaración `T D` en que `D` tiene la forma
>
> **`D1 [` *expresión-constante*<sub>*opcional*</sub> `]` *secuencia-especificación-atributo*<sub>*opcional*</sub>**
>
> y el tipo del identificador en la declaración `T D1` es "*declarador-tipo-lista* `T`", entonces el tipo del identificador de `D` es formación; [...]

Este galimatías viene a decir que para crear una formación<sup>1</sup> de la manera en que lo estás haciendo es imposible (sea de las dimensiones que sea), ya que los tamaños en la definición del array deben ser constantes conocidas en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n), pero el valor de `v` sólo se conoce en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

Para evitar estos problemas, mejor usa `std::vector`:

```
void EDT(ifstream& arch_Datos){
    string texto;
    int i=0;
    int suma;
    float media;
    std::vector<int> longitud; // Un vector
    while(!arch_Datos.eof()){
        getline(arch_Datos,texto);
        longitud.push_back(texto.length()); // Añadimos un dato al vector
        cout<<longitud[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.